# List comprehension with nested list, if statement and range steps

Tags: python

I have a list with the following syntax:

```
list_in = [["Text1","", ["Text2.xml", "Text2.png", ...]], 
         ["Text3", "", ["Text4.xml", "Text4.png", ...]], 
         ["Text5","", ["Text6.xml", "Text6.png", ...]], 
         ["Text7", "", ["Text8.png", "Text8.xml", ...]], 
         ["Text9", "", ["Text10.png", "Text10.xml", ...]], 
         ...]
```

The output I want is a list with concatenation of `list_in[i][0]` with `list_in[i][2]` if `list_in[i][2]` ends with `".xml"` starting at list_in[2] following steps of 2.

Given above example: `list_out = ["Text5Text6.xml", "Text9Text10.xml"]`

I have tried the following code:

```
list_out = [list_in[i][0] + list_in[i][2] for i in range(2, len(input), 2) if i.endswith(".xml")]
```

But it won't work because `list_in[i][2]` is another iterable.
So my question is how can I achieve getting my output given the criteria?

Comment: Thank you for the tip. I'm just using input and output as examples here. But I will keep it in mind.

Comment: Unclear what you're asking, in the question you're refering to the list as a single dimension whereas the code and input aren't. Also please indent your example list so that we can see what's the format.

Comment: You will have to call a for loop on each record in your input, then iterate over your nested list in each record.

Comment: why is `"Text9Text10.xml"` in the desired output?

Comment: Also note that `input[2]` is a list and `input[0]` a string. You cannot concatenate string and list. Do you mean `input[2][0]`?

Comment: You need to wrangle your data before trying to do things like this, I would suggest taking a look at pandas package if your interested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need a second iteration in your comprehension since your `input_[i][2]` is a nested-(nested)-list. So you'll need to iterate through each of those items (I'll call them `filename`s) in your comprehension. You could also iterate through them using a for-loop.

A few minor mistakes include a missing parentheses behind `i.endswith(".xml"` and since `i` is an `int`, it has no `endswith` function.

```
>>> output = [input_[i][0] + filename 
                for i in range(2, len(input_), 2)
                  for filename in input_[i][2]
                    if filename.endswith(".xml")]
>>> output
['Text5Text6.xml', 'Text9Text10.xml']
```

<sub>As I've mentioned before, don't use `input` as a variable name. I'm using `input_` instead just to be clear about this.</sub>

---

That's a pure one-liner hack (or multi-line if you choose to). If you wish to opt for something more ***readable***, consider breaking your comprehension into a loop block.

```
output = []
for i in range(2, len(input_), 2):
  for filename in input_[i][2]:
    if filename.endswith(".xml"):
      output.append(input_[i][0] + filename)
```

Not much difference either way.

Comment: Thank you, I tried your code and it worked. I will take your comments into account the next time I post a question. I will not use `input` as an example variable and will check my code better.

Answer (score 1):

First of all do not use Python built-ins as variable names (`input` in your code). Secondly, what you want is to concatenate `item[0]` of each sublist with the item of the sub-sublist (`item[2]`) that ends with `"xml"`. And that starting from item 2 and with a step of 2. So you do:

```
lst = [["Text1", "", ["Text2.xml", "Text2.png", ...]], 
       ["Text3", "", ["Text4.xml", "Text4.png", ...]], 
       ["Text5", "", ["Text6.xml", "Text6.png", ...]], 
       ["Text7", "", ["Text8.png", "Text8.xml", ...]], 
       ["Text9", "", ["Text10.png", "Text10.xml", ...]], 
         ...]


res = []
for k, _, v in lst[2::2]:
    catch = next((g for g in v if g.endswith('.xml')), None)
    if catch is not None:
        res.append(k+catch)
```

which results in:

```
print(res)  # -> ['Text5Text6.xml', 'Text9Text10.xml']
```

Answer (score 0):

Your output is incorrect or i may have understood it incorrectly....can you explain the final result ?

Also, close your parenthesis here and 'i' is a number:

```
output = [input[i][0] + input[i][2] for i in range(2, len(input), 2) if i.endswith(".xml"]
```

Answer (score 0):

I understand you want to use a comprehension. Here you go...

```
data = [["Text1","", ["Text2.xml", "Text2.png"]],
     ["Text3", "", ["Text4.xml", "Text4.png"]],
     ["Text5","", ["Text6.xml", "Text6.png"]],
     ["Text7", "", ["Text8.png", "Text8.xml"]],
     ["Text9", "", ["Text10.png", "Text10.xml"]]]

x = ["".join(d[:1] + [s for s in d[2] if ".xml" in s]) for d in data[2::2]]
```